# Undefined index

Tags: php, indexing, mysqli, undefined

why do a I get this ( Undefined index: rating) error ?

As you can see I have written "rating" in to the names in the form.

```
 $rating = $_POST['rating'];


            $rate = "INSERT INTO cms_rating (rating, p_id) VALUE ('$rating', '$id')";

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $con->query($rate);

            } else {
            ?>

            <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1">*
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2">**
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3">***
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4">****
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5">*****
            <input type="submit">
            </form> 

            <?php
            };
```

Comment: did you get the desired result or it only shows you the error???

Comment: I get the result, It seems to be working, but why the error ?

Comment: **FYI:** its `VALUES` not `VALUE`, and you should be checking `$_POST['rating']` instead, then put those insertion variables inside the if block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, without submiting, the key 'rating' does not exists in $_POST array, hence the notice. Just change the order if you want this action after submit:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $rating = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rating']);
    $rate = "INSERT INTO cms_rating (rating, p_id) VALUE ('$rating', '$id')";

        $con->query($rate);

        } else {
        ?>

        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1">*
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2">**
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3">***
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4">****
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5">*****
        <input type="submit" name = "submit">
        </form> 

        <?php
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not posting the rating variable

A good practice to check and set value is

```
$rating=0;
if(isset( $_POST['rating']))
     $rating = $_POST['rating'];
```

if it is set, it will assign the posted value else it will have the value 0.

in your case it would be empty first, since you will access the page with GET method so make it as

```
if (isset($_POST['rating'])) {
   //query and rest of the details here..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use 
    ini_set("display_errors","off"); 
in starting of php, notice will dismiss...
```

Comment: Use this configuration only if the user is in production, in development environment it is a good practice to display errors.

Answer (score 0):

this is just the notice you get.
at the top write this

```
ini_set('display_errors','0');
```

it will do the trick..

Comment: Use this configuration only if the user is in production, in development environment it is a good practice to display errors

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** You have to check variable isset and !empty.

**Try this:**

```
if(isset($_POST['rating']) && !empty($_POST['rating'])){
    $rating = $_POST['rating'];
}else{
    $rating = '0';
}

$rate = "INSERT INTO cms_rating (rating, p_id) VALUE ('$rating', '$id')";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $con->query($rate);
} else {

?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1">*
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2">**
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3">***
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4">****
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5">*****
        <input type="submit">
    </form> 

<?php
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the page IS running the script as soon as the page loads. However, the script doesn't yet have the information from the input fields. The solution is very simple and takes only two easy steps:

1) Add a "name" attribute to your submit button in your html.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
```

2) Put this code at the top of your php script and replace it with your submit button's name. The code, when placed at the top of the script, stops the script from running if the form has not been submitted.

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    exit;
}
```

I hope this has helped, and good luck at completing your project.